# Probability of choosing a of b numbers in exactly c guesses

Tags: probability

(This is my first question, and I have not formally learned much probability, so forgive me if this question is too easy.)

Background information: while watching a UK gameshow called [The Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Code_(game_show)), I began wondering how many questions a contestant would need to answer, on average, to win. Relevant to this question, the only thing you need to know about the show is that 3 distinct numbers from 0-9 have been selected, and after answering a question correctly, the contestant chooses a number and gets to see whether it is one of the 3 they are looking for. They need to find all 3 to win.

I'm looking for a general formula for the probability of finding *a* numbers selected out of a character set of *b* in exactly *c* attempts (obviously $a,b,c \in \mathbb N$). In the example that inspired this question, $a = 3$ and $b = 10$ (and I would like to know the probability for all $c \in [3, 10]$, and/or some other way of calculating the median number of guesses necessary).

I have calculated some specific values of *c* as follows:

- For $c = 3$, the player needs to make three correct guesses in a row, with probability $\frac{3}{10}\cdot\frac{2}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{120}$. I notice that this is the reciprocal of ${10 \choose 3}$, but the next example is not $1 \div {10 \choose 4} = \frac{1}{210}$, so I don't think it's that simple.
- For $c = 4$, the player will make three correct guesses and one incorrect one. There are seven incorrect numbers that could be chosen (before the incorrect guess), and there will be a similar 3, 2, 1 pattern to what we saw in the last example for the correct choices. The possible numbers to choose from at each stage will be 10, 9, 8, 7. And finally, there are three potential orders (the incorrect guess can be any of the first three positions, but not the fourth as this is covered by $c=3$). So this gives us the probability: $3 \cdot \frac{7\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7} = \frac{1}{40}$, which I believe is correct.

Are these calculations correct, and if so, how can they be generalised?

Comment: @lulu order matters here - the incorrect guess can't be last.

Comment: @S.Ong  Not sure I understand.  You need to choose $4$ numbers including the correct three...how does order entire into it?

Comment: @lulu You need to choose exactly 4 numbers, but the game ends when you choose the correct 3. So as I mentioned in the question, if you choose the correct 3 as your first guesses, that counts as c = 3, not c = 4: an incorrect guess will never be last, because otherwise the game would have ended by that point.

Comment: To omit conditional probability it is better to always pick four numbers, then probability of each combination will be equal. Those two different approaches should produce the same results.

Comment: not an answer to the question but if this is your start in probability and you can relate to combinatorics maybe relate these things to things like the pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is can be modeled by a [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution for $a-1$ successes out of the first $c-1$ guesses, along with a $\frac{1}{b-c+1}$ chance of getting the last number on the next guess. Plugging in to the formula should give us $\frac{\binom{a}{a-1}\binom{b-a}{c-a}}{\binom{b}{c-1}} \times \frac{1}{b-c+1}$.

Alternatively, this can be seen as the probability of winning in at most $c$ turns but not winning in at most $c-1$ turns. There are $\binom{a}{a}\binom{b-a}{c-a}$ ways to win in $c$ turns, out of a total of $\binom{b}{c}$ possible turns, so this gives us
$$\frac{\binom{a}{a}\binom{b-a}{c-a}}{\binom{b}{c}} - \frac{\binom{a}{a}\binom{b-a}{c-a-1}}{\binom{b}{c-1}}$$
We check to make sure that this matches the above answer:
\begin{align*}
&= \frac{\frac{(b-a)!}{(c-a)!(b-c)!}}{\frac{b!}{c!(b-c)!}} - \frac{\frac{(b-a)!}{(c-a-1)!(b-c+1)!}}{\frac{b!}{(c-1)!(b-c+1)!}}\\
&=\frac{(b-a)!c!}{(c-a)!b!} - \frac{(b-a)!(c-1)!}{(c-a-1)!b!}\\
&=\frac{(b-a)!c!- (c-a)(b-a)!(c-1)!}{(c-a)!b!}\\
&=\frac{(b-a)!(c - (c-a))(c-1)!}{(c-a)!b!}\\
&=\frac{a(b-a)!(c-1)!}{(c-a)!b!}\times\frac{\frac{1}{(b-c)!}}{\frac{1}{(b-c)!}}\\
&=\frac{a\frac{(b-a)!}{(c-a)!(b-c)!}}{\frac{b!}{(c-1)!(b-c)!}}\\
&=\frac{a\binom{b-a}{c-a}}{\frac{b!}{(c-1)!(b-c+1)!}}\times\frac{1}{b-c+1}\\
&=\frac{a\binom{b-a}{c-a}}{\binom{b}{c-1}}\times\frac{1}{b-c+1}\\
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed, this does yield 1/120 and 1/40 for a = 3, b = 10 and c = 3, 4. Then, for c = 5 to 10, the probabilities are: 1/20, 1/12, 1/8, 7/40, 7/30, 3/10.

The mode is 10 and there is only a cumulative probability > 0.5 when you reach 9 guesses, which is larger than I was expecting (and bad news for the gameshow contestants).